# mvc dropdownlistfor is not marked as required but is still required

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, required

I have a dropdownlistfor in cshtml file:

```
var kategorie_wlasna = new SelectList(
  (from z in Model.Kategoria
    where !formReadOnly || z.Id == Model.KategoriaWlasnaId 
      select z), 
  "Id", 
  "Nazwa");
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(
  model => model.KategoriaWlasnaId, 
  kategorie_wlasna,
  "----",
  htmlClassDropDownListDef)
```

In my viewModel I have the property without any annotations as Required:

```
public long KategoriaWlasnaId { get; set; }
```

But the field is still Required. In the browser I get:

```
<select class="input-validation-error form_object1" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field KategoriaWlasnaId must be a number." data-val-required="The KategoriaWlasnaId field is required." id="KategoriaWlasnaId" name="KategoriaWlasnaId">
  <option value="">-----</option>
  <option value="1227">Wykroczenie</option>
  <option value="1228">Przestępstwo</option>
</select>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That's normal. Value types are always required. You could make your property nullable:

```
public long? KategoriaWlasnaId { get; set; }
```

Now it will no longer be required and if the user doesn't select any element in the dropdown its value will be `null`. And if you wanted to make it required and personalize the message you could decorate it with the Required attribute:

```
[Required]
public long? KategoriaWlasnaId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you very match. I have completely missed such trivial solution.

Comment: Thanks. It makes perfect sense that value types has to be "automatically required", yet I also managed to fall for this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the default `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` so that value types will not be required by adding the following lines to `Global.asax.cs` in the Application_Start method:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear(); 
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataValidatorProvider());
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype (use long) is not a must then this will also work by just changing long to string

public long KategoriaWlasnaId  { get; set; }

public string KategoriaWlasnaId { get; set; }

this also

public long? KategoriaWlasnaId { get; set; }

also if you are using data annotations you may can use Nullable attribute as well